# Interface not registered Failed to find proxy registration for IID: {EAC04BC0-3791-11D2-BB95-0060977B464C}

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting this weird error, this is the first time I face this error.

I'm trying to auto complete source textbox.

The error is :

- Exception   Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll ("Interface not registered
  Failed to find proxy registration for IID: {EAC04BC0-3791-11D2-BB95-0060977B464C}.")    System.InvalidCastException

This is my code :

```
Conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT MaterialName FROM Materials where SANF = @SANF", Conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SANF", "fix_parts")
    Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "list")

        Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim i As Integer
    MsgBox(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count)
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("MaterialName").ToString())
        Next
        Conn.Close()
        TxTMaterialName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        TxTMaterialName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
        TxTMaterialName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
```

Comment: That is not unusual, that IID is the one for IAutoComplete2.  You use it when you assign the AutoCompleteXxx properties.  It does not have a proxy, none is ever needed in a proper program.  Set a breakpoint on the method and when it hits use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window.  Ought to show you why this code is running on a worker thread.